# How can I open a file when I do not know what command opens it?

Tags: command-line

Ubuntu noob here. How do I open a file in a working directory? I have already tried

```
./MyFile.jpg
```

And it replies with

```
bash: ./MyFile.jpg: Permission denied
```

Now, that got me thinking that I had to go and change the permissions. So I used chmod to make the file permission "rwx" (I'm not sure if making executable permissible is going to do what I want, it just seemed logical) and tried

```
./MyFile.jpg
```

But this returned

```
bash: ./MyFile.jpg: cannot execute binary file
```

Which makes me think the chmod was not the right way to go. So I changed the permission back so that it was not "rwx", but just "rw-".
Now I'm stuck feeling pretty foolish because I can't open a simple file in Terminal. I can open it by not using Terminal and double clicking on the file while on the Desktop, but I want to teach myself how to navigate using the Terminal. I also tried

```
sudo ./MyFile.jpg
```

but that didn't work either. Any help?

Comment: You're trying to open a JPG Image file as an *executable* with the shell (bash) of course it doesn't work. The correct command would be `eog Myfile.jpg`.

Comment: `.jpg` file? you want to execute an image file? no you cannot.

Comment: @nickanor a file ending in .jpg can be an executable. Linux generally does not check the last part of a file ;)

Comment: @UriHerrera I think the question is `How would I discover that "eog" is the program I need to open this file?`

Comment: +1 because despite having used ubuntu for years, I occasionally hit the same problem with a file type I hadn't seen before.

Comment: Ah this is not a 100% duplicate, as even nautilus or any other filemanager might not know the right program to open a certain file. However, sometime the command `file MyFile.jpg` returns useful information to search for a program that could handle this sort of file.

Answer (score 49):

If you want to use the default program for opening a file you can use

```
gnome-open YourFile
```

or (as Florian Diesch mentioned in a comment) you can use the following command which also works on every [XDG](http://www.freedesktop.org/)-compliant desktop environment (including KDE, LXDE, and XFCE):

```
xdg-open YourFile
```

You have to use a command to open a file. In your case you could use

```
eog MyFile.jpg
```

No need to mess with permissions. Eog is the *eye of gnome*. Type `man eog` for more information. It can open [the following image files](http://projects.gnome.org/eog/): ani, bmp, gif, ico, jpeg, pcx, png, pnm, ras, svg, tga, tiff, wbmp, xbm, and xpm.

For other file types you need other commands. For example:

1. A pdf file called YourMajesty.pdf can be opened with `evince YourMajesty.pdf`.
2. A text file named MyFile.txt can be opened using `gedit MyFile.txt` and that also holds for many other files containing text (but not having a .txt extension).

If you add a  `&` at the end of your command (for instance, `eog MyPhoto.jpg &`) you can still continue using the same terminal for other commands.

Comment: I've found that aliasing `xdf-open` to the simple command `go` works wonders. In Ubuntu you can open a graphical file folder at the current directory simply by typing `go .`.

Comment: gnome-open is good!

Answer (score 10):

If you want to open a file, use `gnome-open`. Think of it as equivalent to double-clicking on the file in Nautilus.

```
gnome-open MyFile.jpg
```

If you want to execute a script or a program, then make its execute permission is set, and type the filename prefixed with the path: (You would never do this with a JPG image, because it is not an executable program.)

```
./executable-name
```

Comment: if you use `xdg-open` instead of `gnome-open` it works on KDE and XFCE, too

Answer (score 4):

In the command line it is not possible to just mention a file and have automatically start the appropriate program with that file.
So you must invoke that program (in this case you can use "Eye of Gnome" hence `eog`).

Try

```
eog Myfile.jpg
```

You can also get back the control of your terminal immediately if you tell eog to launch "in the background" by invoking it with `eog Myfile.jpg &`.

Another hint: use <kbd>tab</kbd> to let the terminal autocomplete your input.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. `xdg-open` does this.